# Get arguments Nginx and path for proxy_pass

Tags: regex, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/images/upload/root/folderA/folderB?arg1=A&arg2=B
```

so, I want redirect all to:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/files_upload/
```

and it must be something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/files_upload/root/folderA/folderB?arg1=A&arg2=B
```

I have the following:

```
location ~ ^/images/upload/([^/]+)(/.*)\?(.*)$ {

     upload_pass @after_upload;
     ...
     ...

}
location @after_upload {
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/v1/files_put/$1/$2?$3;
    }
```

I checked it, and only works **$1** and **$2**, but the arguments $3 are not sent to proxy_pass

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `location` directive doesn't match request arguments, it only checks request path. You should use the `$args` variable (or more specific `$arg_arg1` and `$arg_arg2`):

```
location @after_upload {
    proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080/v1/files_put/$1/$2?$args;
}
```