# Nginx location regex capture variable

Tags: regex, nginx, http-proxy

I have this REST API URL:

```
http://localhost:4000/api/v2/stocks/accounts/1162/tradings
```

I want it to proxy_pass to URL:

```
http://localhost:4001/api/v2/stocks/accounts/1162/tradings
```

Where 1162 is the URL parameter which can be other value.

I have the following:

```
location ^~ /api/v2/stocks/accounts/([^/]+)/tradings {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4001/api/v2/stocks/accounts/$1/tradings;
}
```

But it doesn't work (404 Not Found), I have googled similar problem, but not much help:

Like this one: [Get arguments Nginx and path for proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945208/get-arguments-nginx-and-path-for-proxy-pass) or this one: [trouble with location regex and redirection in nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/414321/trouble-with-location-regex-and-redirection-in-nginx).

Is there any way to achieve what I want, using nginx?

Thanks in advance for any help.

ADDED:

I also added parameters capture:

```
location ~ /api/v2/stocks/accounts/([^/]+)/tradings/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4001/api/v2/stocks/accounts/$1/tradings/$2$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I lost 6 hours trying to figure out this: $2$is_args$args;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it just like this. NOT '**^~**'

```
location ~ /api/v2/stocks/accounts/([^/]+)/tradings {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4001/api/v2/stocks/accounts/$1/tradings;
}
```

As described by [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).
The **^~** is often to match **directory**, like this below:

```
location ^~ /dir/ {
    # some actions
}
```